# Restricting pointer access to stl::vector elements

Tags: c++, stl

Consider case

```
std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5} ;
myOpenCLApi(&v[0]);
```

where as  `myOpenCLApi(void* ptr);`

As one can see evne though it works just fine breaking abstraction of allocator is terrible. How do i stop my clients to avoid such stuff. Question is regarding C++ language features.

Comment: You really can't.  Where there is a will there is a way.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: How do you create a useful tool such as a hacksaw and completely prevent its users from using it dangerously?

Comment: You can provide a C++ interface like `template<IteratorType> myOpenCLApi(IteratorType begin, IteratorType end)` instead.

Comment: My bad, myOpenCLApi refers to my implementation for OpenCL standard. sadly it ccan not be changed to accept Iterators

Comment: Copy it 1st.  Give them a access to a sacrificial copy of the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The C++ language is designed around giving tools to programmers to solve complex problems; it's not designed around making sure programmers can't shoot themselves in the foot using those tools (or, to be more precise: it's not designed around *sacrificing the ability to solve complex problems by making those tools safer to use*).

One thing you *can* do is focus on making sure your *Public API* is as safe to use as possible. In your case, though the use scenario isn't 100% clear, it looks like what you're doing is copying data to the OpenCL API to then be used on the graphics card, and you don't want to have a situation where the programmer has to manually figure out the pointer arithmetic necessary to pass that data along.

The simplest version of this would look something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void copyDataToOpenCL(std::vector<T> const& vec) {
    //There are other things you'll need to do if you're going to use a non-blocking write instead.
    size_t size = vec.size() * sizeof(T);
    clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, buffer, true, 0, size, vec.data(), 0, nullptr, nullptr);
}

/*...*/

std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
copyDataToOpenCL(v);
```

This way, your programmers don't have to directly interface with the underlying memory structure of the vector, which makes things safer. Yes, on the underlying side of things, you're still manipulating raw pointers and data sizes, but your programmers are far less likely to make a mistake when using this code.

But of course, your programmer could still break it like this:

```
std::vector<int> vals = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
std::thread ruiner{[&vals]{
    while(true) {
        vals.emplace_back(vals.back() + 1);
    }
}};
copyDataToOpenCL(vals);
```

But that's the thing: you can't 100% prevent your programmers from doing something stupid. All you can do is try to proof the interface so that more common/simple mistakes get caught.